# Bash regular expressions: Matching numbers 0-1000

Tags: regex, bash, scripting, glob

I'm writing a script that executes scripts stored in a given directory, based on an array containing the filenames of the scripts.
Here's a section of my 'menu', just to clarify:

```
#######

Title: Test script 1
Description: Test script 1
To execute: 0

#######

Title: Test script 2
Description: Test script 2
To execute: 1

#######
```

I have an array named array that contains the names of the scripts with an index corresponding to the printed value under "to execute". Right now, I'm using a case statement to handle input and provide an exit option.

```
case $REPLY in 
     [Ee]) clear
           exit;;
     [[:digit:]] $scriptDirectory/${array[$REPLY]}
```

However, the [[:digit:]] expression only matches 0-9. I need a regex that works in the case statement that matches 0-999, or similar.

Comment: `/\b([1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\b/`

Answer (score 5):

`case` only uses [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) (aka filename expansion patterns), not regular expressions.

You can set [extended glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) with `shopt -s extglob`, then you can use `+()` to match *one or more* occurrence :

```
shopt -s extglob

case $REPLY in 
     [Ee]) clear
           exit;;
     +([[:digit:]])) $scriptDirectory/${array[$REPLY]};;
esac
```

**Note :** I added missing `)` after your second case pattern and missing `;;` at the end of the same line. Also added the `esac` missing statement.

**Update :**

If you just want to match numbers between 0 and 999, try this :

```
     [0-9]?([0-9])?([0-9]))  $scriptDirectory/${array[$REPLY]};;
```

Character range are used here as I find it a bit more readable. The result will be the same.

Comment: nice  :) You might mention that the original code  has some syntax issues too..

Comment: Thanks @sjsam. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the corrections as well. I was using regex before, which explains why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found is bash is:

```
^(1000|[0-9]{1,3})$
```

Using this *regex* combined with the `=~` operator (which interprets the string to the right as an *extended regular expression*) you can construct a simple test. (with your input as `"$1"`)

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^(1000|[0-9]{1,3})$ ]]; then
    echo "0 <= $1 <= 1000 (1)"
else
    echo "$1 - invalid number"
fi
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ for i in -10 -1 0 1 10 100 999 1000 1001; do ./zero1thousand.sh $i; done
-10 - invalid number
-1 - invalid number
0 <= 0 <= 1000
0 <= 1 <= 1000
0 <= 10 <= 1000
0 <= 100 <= 1000
0 <= 999 <= 1000
0 <= 1000 <= 1000
1001 - invalid number
```

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case I suggest you use something like below :

```
REPLY="$1" # I assumed there is an argument to the script

if [[ $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
then
   padded_REPLY=$(printf "%04d" "$REPLY")
   #echo "Padded reply : $padded_REPLY"
else
   padded_REPLY="$REPLY"
   echo "Padded reply : $padded_REPLY"
fi

regexp1="^[[:digit:]]{4}$" #checks padded_REPLY is in the range 0000 to 1000 
#the input is padded 
regexp2="[eE]+$"

if [[ "$padded_REPLY" =~ $regexp1 ]]
then
   if [ "$REPLY" -le 1000 ] #checking script exist
   then
     echo "$REPLY" # I just echoed, you do the stuff below
     #"$scriptDirectory/${array[$REPLY]}"
   else
     echo "Scripts are numbered from 0 to 1000"
   fi       
elif [[ "$padded_REPLY" =~ $regexp2 ]]
then
  clear
  exit
fi
```

But `getopts` is suggested to for smarter argument management.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this:

```
case $REPLY in
  [Ee]) 
        clear
        exit 0;;

  [[:digit:]]|[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]|[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]|1000) 
        $scriptDirectory/${array[$REPLY]}
        exit 0;;
esac
```

The involved *pattern* list matches 1 digit or 2 digits or 3 digits or 1000.

The *pattern* used with `case` is described in [Pattern Matching Notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13) from the Open Group.

Please note that this is not a regular expression.

There is at least one thing taken from Regular Expression; this is the `[]` ([RE Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)). It is used to match a single char. So, `[[:digit:]]` is valid. It matches a single char which could be any digit.

To match several digits, it is needed to concatenate several patterns matching a single character, e.g. use `[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]` to match 2 digits.

`|` can be used to match more than one *pattern*. To match a number between 0 and 99, i.e. one digit or 2 digits numbers, use `[[:digit:]]|[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]`